# Download file programmatically

Tags: java, url, inputstream

I am trying to download an vcalendar using a java application, but I can't download from a specific link.

My code is:

```
URL uri = new URL("http://codebits.eu/s/calendar.ics");
InputStream in = uri.openStream();

int r = in.read();
while(r != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)r);
    r = in.read();
}
```

When I try to download from another link it works (ex: http://www.mysportscal.com/Files_iCal_CSV/iCal_AUTO_2011/f1_2011.ics). Something don't allow me to download and I can't figure out why, when I try with the browser it works.

Comment: The file is moved. Try checking URLConnection from uri.openConnection()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd follow this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-17.html). Basically, get the response code for the connection. If it's a redirect (e.g. 301 in this case), retrieve the header location and attempt to access the file using that.

Simplistic Example:

```
URL uri = new URL("http://codebits.eu/s/calendar.ics");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)uri.openConnection();
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(con.getHeaderField("Location"));

uri = new URL(con.getHeaderField("Location"));
con = (HttpURLConnection)uri.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```

Comment: I can change the url, but the project should work as a web service. And when someone puts a link to a vcalendar like this, my web service will not work properly.

Comment: I checked the example (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/upgrade-guide/article-17.html) and it works. Thank you very much

Comment: No worries. Learnt something new myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check what that link actually provides. For example, it might be a page that has moved, which gives you back an HTTP 301 code. Your browser will automatically know to go and fetch it from the new URL, but your program won't.

You might want to try, for example, [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to sniff the actual traffic when you do the browser request.

Answer (score 0):

I think too that there is a redirect. The browser downloads from ssl secured `https://codebits.eu/s/calendar.ics`. Try using a [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setFollowRedirects%28boolean%29), it should follow redirects automatically:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)uri.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```